# Gsub characters before and after what I want to get out

Tags: r, gsub

I have the following string with a name I wish to get out (remove all special characters etc) like so;

```
"<td><a href=\"/score/Tournament/10000/world-champ-2023\">World Champ 2023</a>"
```

and i wish for it to look like;

```
/10000/world-champ-2023
```

I've tried to use gsub to remove the text around what i want each time but cant quite remember how to do this

Comment: Try `gsub(".*ament|\">Worl.*", "", text)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach that you can consider :

```
gsub(pattern = "<td><a href=\"/score/Tournament/|\">World Champ 2023</a>", replacement = "", text)

"10000/world-champ-2023"
```

Here is another approach :

```
library(stringr)
text <- "<td><a href=\"/score/Tournament/10000/world-champ-2023\">World Champ 2023</a>"
stringr::str_extract_all(text, "\\d{5}/world-champ-\\d{4}")

[[1]]
[1] "10000/world-champ-2023"
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the desired portion is within "..." and is the 4th and 5th /-separated field, we can use read.table.  Note that the _$V2 syntax is relatively new so be sure you have a sufficiently recent version of R. If it is not feasible to update R then replace that line with `with(V2) |>` . First we read "-separated fields into separate columns, take the second, and read /-separated columns pasting together columns 4 and 5.  No regular expressions are used.

```
x |>
  read.table(text = _, sep = '"') |>
  _$V2 |>
  read.table(text = _, sep = "/") |>
  with(paste(V4, V5, sep = "/"))
## [1] "10000/world-champ-2023"
```

### Note

```
x <- "<td><a href=\"/score/Tournament/10000/world-champ-2023\">World Champ 2023</a>"
```